# Find the index in an array of lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a following array. I would like to find the index of the array which has M in the list so it should give me 2.

```
 Array    List
    0 - > B, P , C
    1 - > U, O, L
    2 - > I, N, M

List<string>[] final = new List<string>[3];
```

I tried the following:

```
Array.IndexOf(final,"M")
```

But it does not work and it returns - 1 because second parameter is a list. Please do not use Linq

Answer (score 1):

`Array.IndexOf` will traverse the one dimensional array and never find the search `string` since it will be comparing it to `List<string>`. You will have to traverse through the list of `strings` in you array:

```
public static int FindLetter(IList<string>[] arr, string search)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        if(arr[i].Contains(search)) 
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your "item to search" is a sub item of the list, you would first need to search each list.This can be done with Linq. Combining the result of Linq Query with Array.IndexOf, you can find the result as

```
var result  =  Array.IndexOf(final,final.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(searchString)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put some alternatives, if you wanted to ditch the array you could achieve the following with standard *Linq* methods

```
 var final = new List<List<string>>();

 var item = final.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("M"));
 // do stuff with item result

 var index = final.FindIndex(x => x.Contains("M"));
 // do stuff with the index
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you have a `List<string>` at each index of the array named **final**, so you just can't use `Array.IndexOf`, you have to search for the Key separately at every index. Following code is the working example of what you want to achieve:

```
public static int SearchKey(List<string>[] array, string key)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach(List<String> i in array)
    {
        if(i.Contains(key))
        {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```